# How to run the same script on several Linux systems concurrently

Tags: linux, apache, networking, benchmarking, apache-zookeeper

I have a question related to latency benchmark. I run Apache ZooKeeper in a cluster of 5 machines (one leader and the rest are followers). There is another machine (client) used to sequence send requests to the protocol.

I manage to run a benchmark program which lasts for pre-selected time, aims to send requests simultaneously and continuously to each ZooKeeper server. When the pre-selected time elapses, I can see the latency result.

However, the above benchmark uses only one client machine to run the benchmark code. Now, I want to increase the number of client machines to make more machines send requests simultaneously. Note that I want to use same code above to test the latency.  The question is how to run the benchmark code from different machines simultaneously?

I guess it should be a Linux script which runs in different machines at the same time.

My experiments are runusing remote Linux cluster which is accessed with SSH.

I look forward to hearing from you

Cheers,

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) as it does not seem be a programming question for which StackOverflow is dedicated (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Of course, assuming that you're running the client on GNU/Linux system as well. If that is not the case, you might consider [Super User](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score -1):

[Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) is certainly the kind of tool you're searching for