# Automating run task in several Linux machines using script

Tags: java, linux, automation, linux-standard-base

I have a Java program (/workspace/Task) and I want to run it in several Linux machines (*m1*, *m2*, *m3*... *mn*).

I need to use Linux script to run a program Task on machines one by one. In other words, I want to run the Task on *m1*, when it initials, I run the program on *m2*,... etc. Meaning that the Task must NOT start on new machine until it completely initials on the previous machine.

Comment: I suspect the answer(s) will be the same as for your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178259/how-to-run-the-same-script-on-several-linux-systems-concurrently

Comment: Thank you for replay. I would say the question is completely different. Before I asked about how automatically run a program on different machines. Now I ask about how to initial the program in sequence (order) in different machines. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Have you searched http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for the answer? Does this one help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92664/how-to-deploy-programs-on-multiple-machines

Comment: Oh, I understood the question, and its difference from the other question. The answers on the other questions (these kinds of questions are better asked at unix.stackexchange.com, and you should use ansible) are also answers for this question...

Comment: It seems there is no answer to my question in unix.stackexchange.com.